# Fdisk reports: Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary. Partition created using Parted

Tags: parted, partition-alignment

I used Parted to create a partition on my server `/dev/sdb`. When I run `fdisk -l`,

```
Warning Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary appears.


Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.3 GB, 2000341917696 bytes

255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243194 cylinders, total 3906917808 sectors

Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes

Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

I/O size (minimum/optimal): 262144 bytes / 524288 bytes

Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

/dev/sdb1               1  3906917807  1953458903+  ee  GPT

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

How can i remove the warning?

Comment: with GTP disk, you need to use gdisk

Comment: I see. So I can just ignore the warning being shown by fdisk -l?

Comment: yes. you can ignore it

Answer (score 3):

Don't use fdisk on a GPT-partitioned disk. Fdisk doesn't know about GPT headers and can in some circumstances overwrite them accidentally (this is rare but can happen), and also doesn't understand any of the extra stuff GPT puts in.

If you want to keep the disk as GPT, use gdisk the way you would use fdisk (they're very similar in their interface). If you want to just use an MBR, use gdisk and then the commands `x` followed by `z`, **but remember this will delete everything on your disk** so don't do it unless you don't need any of that data.

TL;DR: fdisk will see GPT-partitioned disks as being out of alignment, so you should either use gdisk going forward, or delete the GPT table and use fdisk.